# Javascript with HTML *and* input field data

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script code in a current page I'm working on - it returns the HTML for the document.  The alert was just debug to see if this code was running.  The current HTML it returns is only the last part of the document, but at least it returns something...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getHtml() {
        var html_source = document.createElement("INPUT");
        html_source.type = "hidden";
        html_source.name = "html_source";
        html_source.value = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        document.forms[0].appendChild(html_source);
        alert('getHtml(): completed...');
    } 
</script>
```

What I need this code to actually do is return the entire page as the HTML string (this page has lots of text fields and other controls), and I need the HTML to actually be marked up with all field data that is currently filled out on the form.  I think this would mean that the value fields for all text inputs would be modified to contain what the control currently contains, returning the HTML as a string like above.

Does anyone have code that will do this?  The reason I need the HTML like that with all fields filled out is so I can convert the HTML form to a PDF document that already has input field data entered, as if the form was already filled out.

The above script will return the HTML, but if I add data to some of the fields in that section of the HTML document, that data isn't evident in the string that code returns.  I need that code to return all the data as well, associated with each field.

I hope this makes sense; basically I'm trying capture to a 100% an HTML document as a string that was already filled out by a user, at the time they click Submit.  Once I have that string, I can do whatever I want with it including send it to another browser instance where it would be rendered as already filled out, or more to the point for me, to a PDF file renderer, converting the HTML form into a PDF file that is already filled out.

Comment: *I need the HTML to actually be marked up with all field data that is currently filled out on the form* <-- Getting the source of the document's HTML won't include the current state of the elements since doing that doesn't affect their HTML attributes only their JavaScript properties.

Comment: *The reason I need the HTML like that with all fields filled out is so I can convert the HTML form to a PDF document that already has input field data entered, as if the form was already filled out.* <-- Why not just let the form submit and then on that destination create the HTML version of the form and then just convert that to a .pdf?

Comment: This is not the right approach and won't work as you think it will. The HTML of the document doesn't change just because you've entered some values into form fields. Those kinds of changes are persisted in the DOM object properties, not the HTML. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/2gep58q6/). You are better off just submitting the form data and during the server processing of the `action`, generate an PDF based on the form data that was submitted.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a trick or an easier way of just iterating through the document as it was, assigning the values of each field to the properties of the controls as a "default" or something, thereby getting rendered in the PDF anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll have to do that.  I'm already processing all the data for the form into a database, I was trying to avoid having to "build the page twice" to do it "once" basically.

Comment: There is no reason at all to save the HTML. You're trying to reinvent the wheel here. On the server-side just extract the submitted data from the request and populate a new page with those values. And don't put them into form fields on that page, since you aren't collecting the data anymore, place the values into standard elements, like `span` as the `.textContent` of the element. Then, you can just create a PDF of that page.